# Query related to creating table in hive while sqoop import

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying for sqoop import from SQL Server into Hive.
When I execute sqoop-import command, the problem is that import task gets completed,
I can see the complete data on HDFS (under /user/hive/warehouse/table_name_dir)
but when I execute "SHOW TABLES " command in HIve CLI I am not able to see the table in the list.

(Once I have tried like: after importing the table same thing happened as above then I run the CREATE TABLE QUERY in Hive CLI taking the same field as that was in imported one and I was able to see and access the table in Hive CLI.  But I dont think this is effective way every time I perform).

Pls suggest me some solution
Is there any step I missed out or is there any problem?
I am not getting why it is happening?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced similar issue and spent almost 4 days on this. I tried almost all the available options, but could not succeed.

Later, I found something interesting at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5887

I think, this issue has been fixed in Hadoop 0.21.0 and later releases. So, if you can uplgrade your version to 0.21.0, this issue might get fixed up. I am trying to upgrade it even.

Thanks,

Raghu

Comment: Actually this thing has happend because I have not used metastore (mostly used MySQL). Later I fixed this issue after vreading a lot of links. And in Hadoop-0.21.0, may be the this issue is fixed because I am using hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2, hive-0.7.1, sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1. By the way Thanks for ansering the question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try **create-hive-table** tool to populate a Hive metastore with the table definition based on the table present in HDFS.

[Follow the link for create-hive-table](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_8)